# Plot two graphs on the same figure in pandas (bar+line)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to plot two graphs on the same figure in pandas. But if one of the graphs **is bar and the index is datetime64/period/python datetime**, then last graph hides the fist one, while the legend is ok.

If index has other types, then both graphs are plotted.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dt_index = pd.to_datetime(['10/12/2010', '11/12/2010', '12/12/2010', '13/12/2010', '14/12/2010'], dayfirst=True)

#with datetime64 index
#second plot overlap fist, while legend is ok
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(20).reshape((5,4)), columns=['a','b','c','d'], index=dt_index)

#without datetime64 index
#two plots on figure
#df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(20).reshape((5,4)), columns=['a','b','c','d'])

ax = df.iloc[:,:3].plot(kind='bar')
df.iloc[:,3:].plot(ax=ax)
```

What's the problem?

python 3.4.3

pandas 0.16.2

numpy 1.9.2

Comment: for me, the code works well [view screen capture](http://screencloud.net/v/ESqv)

Comment: Please be sure to include your Pandas version, e.g. print(pd.__version__).

Comment: Sorry. Pandas 0.16.2.I will try on the other python installation.

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. You need to uncomment line 8 and run test again. On my Mac this code doesn't work too. The same problem.

Comment: [Screenshot](http://prntscr.com/8bwlz3).